# How to change the up axis from y to z in Three.js Editor?

Tags: three.js, editor

My 3d models have the *z-axis as the up axis*.

The default behaviour in Three.js editor is to have *y-axis as the default up axis*.

How can I change it ? I do not want to change the coordinates of my 3D model.

Comment: does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

You have to do these changes

1. In Editor.js add

   ```
   this.scene.rotation.x = - Math.PI/2;
   ```
2. In Viewport.js after add

   ```
   grid.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
   ```